# installing npm with gitlab and ssh give ENOENT errors although the file exists

Tags: node.js, ssh, npm, gitlab

I have been having an issue on Windows 7. I have been using the following npm command to install a package from a git-labs repository.

```
npm install --save git+ssh://git@156.67.38.79:mma/node-typescript-bundle.git
```

The error I get is as follows.

```
It fails with the following.

$ npm install --save git+ssh://git@156.67.38.79:mma/node-typescript-  bundle.git
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install   C:\Users\Operator\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-7556-2bcb63a8\git-cache-ff531437\b3f389becc07c9c83e86c17919f3e869f098f123
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program  Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "git+ssh://git@156.67.38.79:mma/node-typescript-bundle.git"
npm ERR! node v6.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Operator\Dev\npm-ccache\node-typescript -bundle\1.0.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall scandir

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\Operator\Dev\npm-ccache\node-typescript-bundle\1.0.0\package.tgz'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir'C:\Users\Operator\Dev\npm-ccache\node-typescript-bundle\1.0.0\package.tgz'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Operator\Desktop\npm-debug.log
```

I have taken the following steps.

- Updated npm and node
- Recreated the folders
- npm cache clean
- using the command prompt as administrator.
- Searching for similar issues on google and stack overflow.

I am not sure what the issue is and any help would be appreciated. Usual npm install commands work perfectly fine.